# What is causing Flask to not start running?

Tags: python, api, flask, raspberry-pi

I have been working on some code for a while now, but haven't had a chance to look at it for two weeks. I've just come back to it, and really cannot figure out why it isn't working. I thought it was working when I left it (Not perfectly, as it isn't finished) but I keep getting errors for Flask itself, but only with this code. Please could someone take a look and see if there is anything glaringly obvious?

```
# add flask here
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

# keep your code
import time
import cgi
import json

from tellcore.telldus import TelldusCore
core = TelldusCore()
devices = core.devices()

# define a "power ON api endpoint"
# START ENDPOINT DECLARATION

@app.route("/API/v1.0/power-on",methods=['POST'])

def powerOnDevice():

        payload = {}
        payload['success'] = False
        payload['message'] = "An unspecified error occured"
        #get the device by id somehow


        # get some extra parameters
        # let's say how long to stay on

        # PARAMS MUST BE HERE
        #params = request.json

        jsonData = request.get_json()
        print jsonData['deviceID']

        device = -1
        powerAction = "none"
        time = 0
        password = "none"

        #checks to make sure the deviceId has been specified and is a valid number
        try:
                device = devices[int(jsonData['deviceID'])]
        except:
                payload['message'] = "Incorrect deviceId specified"
                return jsonify(**payload)

        #checks to make sure the powerAction has been specified and is valid text
        try:
                powerAction = jsonData['powerAction']

                if (jsonData['powerAction'] == "on" or jsonData['powerAction'] == "off"):
                        powerAction = jsonData['powerAction']
        except:
                payload['message'] = "Incorrect powerAction specified"
                return jsonify(**payload)

        #check password is specified and is text
        try:
                password = jsonData['password']

                if (jsonData['password']

        #check time is number and is specified


        if (jsonData['pass'] == "support"):

                try:
                        device.turn_on()
                        payload['success'] = True
                        payload['message'] = ""
                        return jsonify(**payload)

                except:
                        payload['success'] = False
                        # add an exception description here
                        return jsonify(**payload)
        else:
                payload['message'] = "Incorrect password"
                # END ENDPOINT DECLARATION
                return jsonify(**payload)

# define a "power OFF api endpoint"
@app.route("/API/v1.0/power-off/<deviceId>",methods=['POST'])
def powerOffDevice(deviceId):
    payload = {}
    #get the device by id somehow
    device = devices[int(deviceId)]
    try:
      device.turn_off()
      payload['success'] = True
      return payload
    except:
      payload['success'] = False
      # add an exception description here
      return payload

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81, debug=True)
```

When run, I get this:

```
pi@FOR-PI-01 ~/FlaskTesting $ sudo python flaskao150514.py
  File "flaskao150514.py", line 71
    if (jsonData['pass'] == "support"):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then deleting the whole if statement gives me errors with the app.run at the bottom. I know there may be Python mistakes in there, but why isn't Flask running?

Comment: Look at the line of code above that. It's incomplete. (And, in general, if you can't spot a syntax error on the line where it's reported, in any language, check the previous line for unclosed brackets or other missing punctuation.)

Comment: I feel stupid now! Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind when I see error's in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left an incomplete line *before* the line that throws the syntax error:

```
if (jsonData['password']
```

Because there is no closing parenthesis there, Python is looking at following lines to see where the expression ends.

Note that Python does *not need* those parenthesis; the following is valid Python:

```
if jsonData['pass'] == "support":
```

Go easy on the parenthesis and you'll create fewer opportunities for such errors.

Comment: I feel stupid now haha! Thank you, I didn't know that. Think I should go back to Codecademy and learn the basics again.